# Find the derived set of $A=\{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{5^p}:m,n,p\in\Bbb {N}\}.$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the derived set of $A=\{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{5^p}:m,n,p\in\Bbb {N}\}.$

I could find out that the derived set (or the set of all limit points) of $A$ is, $$A'=\{\frac{1}{2^m},\frac{1}{3^n},\frac{1}{5^p}, (\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{3^n}),(\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{5^p}),(\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{5^p}),0\},$$ where $m,n,p \in\Bbb N.$ However, I dont realize whether should I prove that there does not exist limit points other than the ones in $A'.$ *Or is this sufficient as an "answer" to this problem?*

But suppose, I want to prove that there does not exist other limit points, then it seems a really huge task if we try to prove by contradiction method, i.e first taking the case, if $\frac{1}{p^a}$ (, where $p$ is a prime $\neq 2,3,5$ ) is a limt point, then $\frac{1}{\text{product of primes}}$, and finally for all irrationals, and integers positive and negative, apart from $0$. Is there any shorter way to prove this?

Comment: How did sequences turn into series?

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, I am sorry, mistakenly I typed on some random stuffs. Fixed it.

Comment: Okey dokey. .... :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\alpha \notin A'$ but $\alpha$ is a limit point of $A$. There there is a non-constant sequence of points
$$
\frac{1}{2^{m_k}}+\frac{1}{3^{n_k}}+\frac{1}{5^{p_k}} \to \alpha
$$
as $k \to \infty$.

Notice that if a sequence of integers is bounded, then it contains a constant subsequence. In addition, if a sequence of natural numbers is unbounded, then it contains a subsequence tending to infinity.

Suppose $m_k$ is bounded. Then passing to a constant subsequence (say $m_{k_j} = \frac{1}{2^r}$), we find that
$$
\frac{1}{3^{n_{k_j}}}+\frac{1}{5^{p_{k_j}}} \to \alpha - \frac{1}{2^r},
$$
where $\frac{1}{2^r}$ denotes the constant term. If $m_k$ is not bounded, then it contains a subsequence $m_{k_j}$ going to infinity, and thus
$$\frac{1}{2^{n_{k_j}}} \to 0,$$ so that
$$
\frac{1}{3^{n_{k_j}}}+\frac{1}{5^{p_{k_j}}} \to \alpha.
$$
Repeat the argument for $n_k$ and then $p_k$, to find that the limit $\alpha$ must be in $A'$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! But comsidering the way the questioon is given, do I really have to prove that no other limit points exist(, in an answer)? Or the listing of the limit points will suffice ?

Comment: To show that your list is indeed complete, yes you have to prove that there are no other limit points.