# If $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2\in\mathbb{N};\ (a_1,b_1)\neq (a_2,b_2),$ show that $\frac{1}{2^{a_1}}+\frac{1}{3^{b_1}}\neq\frac{1}{2^{a_2}}+\frac{1}{3^{b_2}}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I came up with this question whilst thinking about how to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718211/find-the-derived-set-of-a-frac12m-frac13n-frac15pm-n-p-in).

If $(a_1,b_1) \neq (a_2,b_2)\ $ where $\ a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2 \in\mathbb{N},\ $ show that $$ \frac{1}{2^{a_1}} + \frac{1}{3^{b_1}} \neq \frac{1}{2^{a_2}} + \frac{1}{3^{b_2}} .$$

Attempt: Suppose $a_i, b_i\in\mathbb{N}$ and

$$ \frac{1}{2^{a_1}} + \frac{1}{3^{b_1}} = \frac{1}{2^{a_2}} + \frac{1}{3^{b_2}}.$$

Suppose further that $a_2 > a_1.$ Then, $ \frac{1}{2^{a_2}} < \frac{1}{2^{a_1}},$ so $ \frac{1}{3^{b_2}} -  \frac{1}{3^{b_1}} > 0 \implies b_1 > b_2.\ $

Next, we have:

$$\frac{1}{2^{a_1}} - \frac{1}{2^{a_2}} = \frac{1}{3^{b_2}} - \frac{1}{3^{b_1}},\ \implies \frac{2^{a_2-a_1} - 1}{2^{a_2}} = \frac{3^{b_1-b_2} - 1}{3^{b_1}} $$

$$ \implies 3^{b_1}\left( 2^{a_2-a_1} - 1 \right) = 2^{a_2}\left(  3^{b_1-b_2} - 1\right) \quad (*) $$

Since $a_2 > a_1$ and $b_1 > b_2,$ every term in $(*)$ is a positive integer. In particular, the LHS of $(*)$ is odd and the RHS of $(*)$ is even, a contradiction. The shows that $a_2 \not> a_1.$

If we instead suppose $a_1>a_2$ then we get a similar contradiction (the same, but with $a_1 \leftarrow\rightarrow  a_2$ and $b_1\leftarrow\rightarrow b_2.)$ Therefore, $a_1 = a_2,\ \implies b_1=b_2,\ $ as desired; that is, we proved the contrapositive of the proposition.

1. Is this correct?
2. Is this the standard/easiest approach to answer this question?

I also thought of starting with, "Suppose $(a_1,b_1) \neq (a_2,b_2).$ Then, $2^{a_1}3^{b_1} \neq 2^{a_2}3^{b_2},\ $ by the fundamental theorem of algebra." This feels relevant, but I'm not sure where to take this.

Comment: I did exactly the same as you after looking only at your title. Except that I wrote "wlog, $a_2>a_1$" instead of "Suppose further that".

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks for your comment. Yes I did that at first too. But I wanted to make the proof more explicit so it can be more easily understood by everyone (esp. people who don't understand about WLOG).

Comment: This is admittedly overkill, but are you familiar with [$p$-adic valuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation)? The claim follows immediately from the non-archimedean triangle inequality (applied to both $2$-adic and $3$-adic valuations).

Comment: @Jyrki no I'm not.

Comment: Bringing up the $p$-adic valuation is overkill for the following reason. The representation of a rational number as a fraction $r/s$ in the reduced form, i.e. $\gcd(r,s)=1$, is unique up to sign. The denominators of the reduced forms of these numbers are $2^{a_i}3^{b_i}$ with $i=1,2$ respectively. There may be a special case when there are zeros among the exponents.

Comment: That uniqueness is a consequence of the unique factorization of integers, as you foresaw actually!

Comment: The uniqueness (under reasonable restrictions) of *partial fraction decomposition* also works for integers instead of polynomials. For instance, for any natural numbers $m,n$ coprime and $z,$ there exists at most one pair of natural numbers $x\in[0,m)$ and $y\in[0,n)$ such that
$$\frac z{mn}=\frac xm+\frac yn\quad\text{i.e.}\quad z=xn+ym.$$
Indeed, if $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ are two such pairs then $m\mid x-x'\in(-m,m)$ hence $x'=x$ and therefore $y'=y.$

Answer (score 2):

Note $a,b,c,d$  the given integers.
It is equivalent to prove $$\frac{1}{2^a}+\frac{1}{3^b}=\frac{1}{2^c}+\frac{1}{3^d}\Rightarrow (a,b)=(c,d)$$ We have $$\frac{1}{2^a}+\frac{1}{3^b}=\frac{1}{2^c}+\frac{1}{3^d}\iff\frac{1}{2^a}-\frac{1}{2^c}=\frac{1}{3^d}-\frac{1}{3^b}$$ This equality is not possible, except when both sides are zero because if not then the $LHS$ is a finite decimal while the $RHS$ is periodic (not finite) decimal. We are done.